# How to compute correlation of a pandas dataframe with NaN in it

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics, pearson-correlation

I computed the correlation of a DataFrame in pandas but why does it give NaN for correlation between columns 1 and 2 and 1 and 4, when there is a common element between columns 1 and 4.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0frc.jpg]

Comment: You can't do correlation coefficient off a single element. What should the variances and covariances be? In the 1, 4 case all the surviving elements of col 4 are equal, so variance is zero.

Comment: in case of columns 1 and 3 there is a single element 3 and the correlation should be 1. and in case of columns 1 and 4 it should have returned 0 atleast instead of NaN.

Comment: I think it would be a good exercise for you to look up the formula for correlation coefficient and try and apply it to the valid elements of column pairs 1, 2 and 1, 4; you'll find that `nan` is the correct answer in both cases.